# Adding a specific collection to a specific page in Shopify

Tags: json, shopify, themes, liquid

When trying to add a collection to a specific page eg. a brand collection on the Gaming page, the collection will appear on all pages. How do I make sure that if I add one collection to a page it only appears on that page. I am using the Dawn Shopify theme.

I have tried changing the theme as indicated by the picture below but I cannot seem to add a new theme except the 'Default page'.[image: highlighted page editing view]

Answer (score 0):

A page in Shopify is a unique resource. That page has specific content you write in it. So if you have a page known as **gaming**, you are free to write about gaming in that page. You could also include liquid in that page that would render a specific collection. As an example you have a special collection with the handle **special-gaming** you can include that collection on this page.

You could also create a new template for pages. Call it **gaming-page** and it is a duplicate of your regular page. But, you edit that liquid, and add in special code to access that special collection. Now, you would just write your page as is, for gaming, but you'd select the new **gaming-page** template from the online store theme template.

If you experiment with Shopify you'll figure it out. Just play. No better way to learn than to experiment!